# Undocumented API resource for clockify

Tags: swagger, clockify

is there an undocumented operation for an authentification request with email and password? I found an AuthenticationRequest in your [working API](https://clockify.github.io/clockify_api_docs/#definition-AuthenticationRequest) without a related operation.

We could handle the API request with the X-Api-Key from an admin account, but this will increase security aspects.

One last note: It would be great, if you can share the swagger json file.

**Update**

[Answer by clockify](https://forum.clockify.me/t/undocumented-api-resource-authentificationrequest/74)

Comment: Did you mean to post this question on their forum? https://forum.clockify.me

Comment: They recommended it [1st paragraph](https://clockify.me/developers-api), but thanks for the hint. I will post it there, too.